# How to send transaction using ethereum contract?

Tags: solidity, python, django

I made ethereum contract according to sample code. And then generated ethereum wallet. The abstract contract is as follow.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}
```

Now I want to send ether to other using this contract. How to send transaction using contract? plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

let the address you wish to transfer ether to be adr

```
adr.transfer(1000);
```

the value inside transfer would be in Wei

Comment: Hi @Skyuppercut. This answer is helpful for me, but not enough to understand. plz tell me in detail. thanks.

Comment: transfer is an inbuilt function of type 'address'. It can be used to send ether to addresses. Start reading the documentation [link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related)